# how to supress warning "gets() is deprecated"?

Tags: gcc, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

everytime i try to input my string using `gets()` function, my compiler gives me warning like shown below. how to get rid of this. what am i doing wrong?

```
test.c:27:2: warning: ‘gets’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/stdio.h:638) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
gets(temp);
^
```

Comment: Simple: stop using gets, it's deprecated

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `fgets` instead:

```
fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), stdin);
```

`gets` is deprecated because it's dangerous, it may cause buffer overflow.