# Why and how gcc emits warning for gets()?

Tags: c, gcc, gets

```
while(1)
    {
        printf("\nEnter message : ");
        gets(message);

        //Send some data
        if( send(sock , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
        {
            puts("Send failed");
            return 1;
        }

        //Receive a reply from the server
        if( recv(sock , server_reply , 2000 , 0) < 0)
        {
            puts("recv failed");
            break;
        }

        puts("Server reply :");
        puts(server_reply);
    }

    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

This is part of my program. When I compile and run it, I get an error. The error's message is

> warning: the gets function is dangerous and should not be used!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to supress warning "gets() is deprecated"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192934/how-to-supress-warning-gets-is-deprecated)

Comment: a compiler warning and a compiler error - are both different. May be related, yes, but, very different.

Comment: Yes, `gets` is depreciated and now removed after c11.`gets_s` was introduced as a safer alternative.

Comment: use fgets like this  `fgets(array, sizeof(arr), stdin)` or `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", arr)` remember to chop off the `\n` in case of `fgets`

Comment: @ARBY Please note that gets_s() is just there for backwards compatibility reasons, the standard itself recommends using fgets().

Answer (score 4):

A simple google search would have given a lot of useful information like this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1694042/2425366

A buffer overflow example using `gets`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char buff[15];
    int pass = 0;
    printf("\n Enter the password : \n");
    gets(buff);
    if (strcmp(buff, "thegeekstuff")) {
        printf("\n Wrong Password \n");
    }
    else {
        printf("\n Correct Password \n");
        pass = 1;
    }
    if (pass) {
        /* Now Give root or admin rights to user*/
        printf("\n Root privileges given to the user \n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Input 1**

```
thegeekstuff
```

**Output**

```
 Correct Password
 Root privileges given to the user
```

**Input 2**

```
abcdefghijklmnopqr    <-- stack smashing
```

**Output**

```
 Wrong Password
 Root privileges given to the user
```

Answer (score 3):

### Regarding the issue:

`gets()` function is dangerous for the risk of buffer overflow and dropped from the standard `C`, as per `C11` standard. Compilers may support them for backward compatibility for legacy codes.

FWIW, this warning is not issued by `gcc` all by itself. Most likely, `glibc`  contains a pragma which causes the compiler to emit the warning. <sup>[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1694042/2173917)</sup>

### Regarding the error:

You have [`-Werror`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) enabled in your compilation statement, which basically asks `gcc` to treat any warning as error.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us how you had declared the variable `message` which you passed as the argument to `gets`.  Suppose it was

```
char message[100];
```

Now suppose that the actual line of input that your program ends up trying to read is 200 characters long.  The array will overflow, with potentially disastrous results.  (Seriously: honest-to-goodness major security breaches have resulted from using `gets`.)

No matter how big your array is, the input might always be bigger, and there's no way to prevent the overflow, because there's no way to tell `gets` how big your array actually is.  That's why you should never use it.