# Counting number of sentences in C

Tags: c

This simple code counts number of sentences entered by checking period, question mark or exclamation mark. However, if I enter " ", it does not count sentences after space.
How can I fix this?

```
int numberSentence(char ch[])
{
    int count=0, i=0;
    while(ch[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(ch[i] == '.' || ch[i] == '?' || ch[i] == '!')
            count++;
        i++;
    }

    return count;
}


int main()
{
    char ch[999];
    printf("Enter sentences:\n");
    scanf("%s", ch);
    printf("Number of sentences is %d", numberSentence(ch));

}
```

Comment: blank as in you type the letters `b`, `l`, `a`, etc.., or you hit the space bar?

Comment: Is your blank included `'\t'`, `' '`, `''`, `'\n'` or `'\r'`?

Comment: A little more explicit please.

Comment: Add a newline: `printf("Number of sentences is %d\n", numberSentence(ch) );`

Comment: sorry, yes I meant space bar

Comment: I think better way to think of the code you have here is to see it as a counter of `.`,  `?`, and `!` not as a counter of sentences. Can you give an explicit example of input you've given and output you've received?

Comment: @havada  If you increment after every encounter of a space, you will be basically counting the number of words instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies at:

```
scanf("%s", ch)
```

scanf with "%s" will look until it finds a white-space, then storing the string into your pointer, ch.

In this case I would suggest using:

```
scanf("%c", ch)
```

Where it will scan character by character. You will need to slightly remodel the program.

Note that scanf() will return an integer representing the width of what it read.
Thus:

```
while(scanf("%c", ch) == 1)
   if (ch == ...)
}
```

For your reference:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm

Answer (score 1):

If by blank you mean new line key, try:

```
if(ch[i] == '.' || ch[i] == '?' || ch[i] == '!' || ch[i] == '\n')
        count++;
```

but why not just use gets() instead?

```
while(gets(ch)!=NULL)
{
    count++;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", ch);` does not include white-space.

Comment: [please, no `gets()`, suggest `fgets()` instead.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31333305/2173917)

Comment: @Dr.Haimovitz Please see ^^.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int numberSentence(char ch[]){
    int count=0, i;
    char last = ' ';

    for(i = 0; ch[i]; ++i){
        if(ch[i] == '.' || ch[i] == '?' || ch[i] == '!'){
            count++;
            last = ' ';
        } else if(ch[i] == ' ' || ch[i] == '\t' || ch[i] == '\n'){
            continue;//white-space does't include to sentence of top.
        } else {
            last = ch[i];//check for Not terminated with ".?!"
        }
    }

    return count + (last != ' ');//+ (last != ' ') : +1 if Not terminated with ".?!"
}


int main(void){
    char ch[1000];

    printf("Enter sentences:\n");
    scanf("%999[^\n]", ch);//input upto newline
    printf("Number of sentences is %d", numberSentence(ch));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this simple problem, you can let `scanf()` split your input on your sentence delimiters using the *scanset* conversion specifier.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int count = 0;
    char buf[1000];
    while (scanf("%999[^.!?]%*c", buf) == 1) ++count;
    printf("sentences: %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

The `%[^.!?]` will scan all the data up to either a period, exclamation point or question mark. The `%*c` will scan past the punctuation without storing it (the `*` means there is no argument for the scanned input to be stored into).