# Struct Array Error

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Student
{
   int GL;
   char FN[80];
   char LN[80];
   double GPA;

}SArray[956];

int main(void)
{
   int OP = 0;
   int i;
   int x = 0;
   struct Student SArray[956];

   while(x == 0)
   {
      printf("Welcome to teh ARX7 SYSTEM. Enter 1 to enter information, 2.............\n");
      scanf("%d", &OP);

      if (OP == 1)
      {
         printf("Enter Student ID:\n");
         scanf("%d", &i);

         printf("Enter Grade Level:\n");
         scanf("%d",&SArray[i].GL);

         printf("Enter First Name:\n");
         gets("%s",&SArray[i].FN);

         printf("Enter Last Name:\n");
         gets("%s",&SArray[i].LN);

         printf("Enter GPA:\n");
         scanf("%lf", &SArray[i].GPA);
      }

      if (OP == 2)
      {
         printf("Enter Student ID:\n");
         scanf("%d", &i);

         printf("Grade: %d",&SArray[i].GL);
         printf("First name: %s\n", SArray[i].FN);
         printf("Last name: %s\n", SArray[i].LN );
         printf("GPA: %lf ", &SArray[i].GPA);
      }
   }
}
```

I'm trying to create a program that stores and displays data for students. However, I keep getting these two errors:

```
main.c:71:23: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
                    printf("Grade: %d",&SArray[i].GL);


main.c:74:24: warning: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'double *' [-Wformat]
                    printf("GPA: %lf ", &SArray[i].GPA);
```

INPUT:

```
Welcome to teh ARX7 SYSTEM. Enter 1 to enter information, 2.............
1
Enter Student ID:
1
Enter Grade Level:
2
Enter First Name:
ee
Enter Last Name:
eee
Enter GPA:
3
```

OUPUT:

```
Welcome to teh ARX7 SYSTEM. Enter 1 to enter information, 2............. 
2
Enter Student ID:
1
Grade: -1264132192
First name: ee
Last name: eee
GPA: 0.000000
```

Comment: `scanf` needs a pointer to the object, so that it can store a value in the object. `printf` just needs the value of the object. So `scanf` needs `&i` (the address of `i`) whereas `printf` just needs `i` (the value of `i`). Also, `gets` is evil and should not be used. Use `fgets` instead. And consult the documentation, since you weren't calling `gets` correctly anyways.

Comment: The error went away, but now I'm getting incorrect output for Grade Level and GPA. My program outputs the correct first and last name inputted, but this not the case for GL and GPA. Thoughts as to why?

Comment: Nope, no idea. Might help to add the terminal contents (i.e. user input and program output) for a sample run.

Comment: That was a single run.

Comment: What did you do about the `gets`? Please add the updated code to the question.

Comment: My teacher said using gets was fine, and I'm not sure how to use fgets.

Comment: Ok, but `gets` only takes one argument, e.g. `gets(SArray[i].FN);`

Comment: See this other question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192934/how-to-supress-warning-gets-is-deprecated) for help on how to use `fgets` instead of `gets`.

Answer (score 2):

Take out the '&' in lines 71 and 74. You're providing the printf function a pointer to the value you want - its address - instead of the value itself.

Answer (score 0):

- You are declaring the array of `struct` named `SArray[956]` twice, once gloabally and once locally too, don't do that, and no need for `struct` keyword when using `typedef` like this.
- Also, passing an array by its name readily gets its reference, so do not use `&` for `FN` and `LN`.
- And dont use `&` for passing a variable to `printf`
- Also, `gets` needs no format specifier such as `%s`. (`gets` is depricated and you should prefer using `fgets` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192934/how-to-supress-warning-gets-is-deprecated).)
- The `getchar()` before first `gets` is to ignore the extra `\n` in the stream because of the last `scanf`.

Just making these changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct
{
   int GL;
   char FN[80];
   char LN[80];
   double GPA;

}Student;

int main(void)
{
   int OP = 0;
   int i;
   int x = 0;
   Student SArray[956];

   while(x == 0)
   {
      printf("Welcome to teh ARX7 SYSTEM. Enter 1 to enter information, 2.............\n");
      scanf("%d", &OP);

      if (OP == 1)
      {
         printf("Enter Student ID:\n");
         scanf("%d", &i);

         printf("Enter Grade Level:\n");
         scanf("%d",&SArray[i].GL);

         getchar();
         printf("Enter First Name:\n");
         gets(SArray[i].FN);

         printf("Enter Last Name:\n");
         gets(SArray[i].LN);

         printf("Enter GPA:\n");
         scanf("%lf", &SArray[i].GPA);
      }

      if (OP == 2)
      {
         printf("Enter Student ID:\n");
         scanf("%d", &i);

         printf("Grade: %d\n",SArray[i].GL);
         printf("First name: %s\n", SArray[i].FN);
         printf("Last name: %s\n", SArray[i].LN );
         printf("GPA: %lf\n", SArray[i].GPA);
      }
   }
}
```